# Proving $a^ab^bc^c\ge(abc)^{(a+b+c)/3}$ for positive real numbers.

Tags: inequality

Prove that

$$a^ab^bc^c\ge(abc)^{(a+b+c)/3}$$

where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R^+}$

I tried using powered AM-GM but didn't get anything. please give me a hint to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

Since $\log(x)$ is monotonically increasing, we have
$$
(a-b)(\log(a)-\log(b))\ge0\\
(c-a)(\log(c)-\log(a))\ge0\\
(b-c)(\log(b)-\log(c))\ge0\\
$$
Add these and
$$
(a\log(a)+b\log(b)+c\log(c))-(a\log(a)+b\log(b)+c\log(c))\ge0
$$
to get
$$
3(a\log(a)+b\log(b)+c\log(c))-(a+b+c)(\log(a)+\log(b)+\log(c))\ge0
$$
Divide by $3$ and exponentiate to get
$$
a^ab^bc^c\ge(abc)^{\frac{a+b+c}3}
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$a^ab^bc^c\ge{(abc)^\frac{a+b+c}{3}} \stackrel{\log (\cdot)}{\iff} a\log a+b\log b+c\log c \geq (\log a+\log b+\log c)\cdot \frac{a+b+c}{3}$$

You can use Chebyshev's sum inequality to finish it.

Answer (score 2):

Take the $\log$ of both sides. This is equivalent to:
$$
a\log a + b\log b + c\log c \ge \frac{a+b+c}3 (\log a + \log b + \log c)
$$

now use the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) twice to get:

$$
a\log a + b\log b + c\log c \ge b\log a + c\log b + a\log c ;\\
a\log a + b\log b + c\log c \ge c\log a + a\log b + b\log c;\\
a\log a + b\log b + c\log c = a\log a + b\log b + c\log c.
$$
The sum of these inequalities is the right result.

---

Alternative:

$$
\frac{a+b+c}3 \frac{\log a + \log b + \log c}3
\le \frac{a+b+c}3 \log   \frac{a+b+c}3
$$using the concavity of $\log$;
$$
\le \frac{a\log a + b\log b + c\log c }3
$$using convexity of $x\to x\log x$.

Comment: We can not divide by $\log a+\log b+\log c$, as it can be negative.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis i fixed it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First Prove that $$a^ab^b\ge a^bb^a$$
Then w have
$$a^ab^b\ge a^bb^a$$
 $$a^ac^c\ge a^cc^a$$
 $$c^cb^b\ge b^cc^b$$

$$a^ab^bc^c\ge a^a b^bc^c$$

Multiplying together

$$a^{3a}b^{3b}c^{3c}\ge (abc)^{a+b+c}$$

$$a^{a}b^{b}c^{c}\ge (abc)^{(a+b+c)/3}$$

Comment: I did not downvote, but perhaps a good hint would be something like $\left(\frac ab\right)^{a-b}\ge1$ by considering the cases $a\ge b$ and $a\lt b$,