# I conjecture $3(a^ab^bc^c)^{\frac{1}{a+b+c}}\ge (a^ab^b)^{\frac{1}{a+b}}+(b^bc^c)^{\frac{1}{b+c}}+(c^ca^a)^{\frac{1}{c+a}}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> I Conjecture, for $a, b, c > 0$,
> $$3\left(a^ab^bc^c\right)^{\dfrac{1}{a+b+c}}\ge \left(a^ab^b\right)^{\frac{1}{a+b}}+\left(b^bc^c\right)^{\frac{1}{b+c}}+\left(c^ca^a\right)^{\frac{1}{c+a}}.$$

This conjecture is based on the problem (use Jensen inequality can prove it):
[Prove $a^ab^bc^c\ge (abc)^{\frac{a+b+c}3}$ for positive numbers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109783/prove-aabbcc-ge-abc-fracabc3-for-positive-numbers?lq=1)

[Prove that $a^ab^bc^c\ge (abc)^{(a+b+c)/{3}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073068/prove-that-aabbcc-ge-abcabc-3?noredirect=1&lq=1)

It seem is right,I can't find count-example  so far,because $(a,b,c)=(1,1,1),(1,2,3)$ is hold,and $(a,b,c)=(x,y,\to 0)$ also hold.and jensen inequality Can't use?

Comment: My bet is that through suitable substitutions this boils down to [Karamata's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality).